# Storing a date as a variable and using it in code (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

Oracle Version: 19.2.1.247

Good morning,

I am trying to get the most recent Friday and then store that date to use as a variable. I need to only bring forward those people who have a start date of 28 days or earlier from "my_date". Anyone over 28 days should be excluded.

here is what I have so far:

```
variable my_date varchar2(30)
exec :my_date := sysdate;

SELECT Distinct * from tbl1.people 
where startdt < to_date(:my_date,(select next_day(trunc(sysdate-1), 'FRIDAY'-7 from dual))-35;
```

I am getting the following error message and I am not sure how to handle it:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected date got date

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
Last Friday (Oct 23, 2020) is "my_date", so I need to go backwards for 28 days to Sept 25, 2020  and use that as the cutoff date. I do not want to see anyone with Sept 24,2020 or earlier.

The result set should be from Sept 25, 2020 to Oct 23, 2020 only.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks as simple as

```
select *
from your_table
where startdt < next_day(sysdate - 7, 'FRIDAY') - 28;
```

because

```
SQL> select next_day(sysdate - 7, 'FRIDAY') - 28 from dual;

NEXT_DAY(S
----------
25.09.2020

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! While the code does process, it is pulling dates back to 2003. I checked the column field for the date and it is set to date. However, in the table (I think this is normal) the dates are surrounded by tick marks. '01/09/2003' - no errors, but not limiting the dates.I don't have a ton of oracle exp, so I maybe missing something.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I needed to switch the < to > and it worked. Thank you again for all your help!